# Prove that $P(\left|Z\right|\leq z) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{e^{-z^2/2}}{z} \left(1 + \mathcal{O} \left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)\right)$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need to solve the following exercise:

> Let $Z$ be a random variable with the standard normal $N(0,1)$- distribution. Prove that
>
> \begin{align*}
> P(\left|Z\right|\leq z)
> &= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{e^{-z^2/2}}{z} - \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}\int_z^\infty x^{-2}e^{-x^2/2} \, dx \\
> &= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{e^{-z^2/2}}{z} \left(1 + \mathcal{O} \left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)\right).
> \end{align*}

I know (at least I think I do) that

$$ P(\left|Z\right|\geq z) = \int_z^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) \, dx $$

Knowing what I need to show, I think I need to apply integration by parts. Unfortunately, I have no idea how. If I let $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ be $f$ and $\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)$ be $g'$ then I have no idea how I could use

$$\int fg' \, dx = fg - \int f'g \, dx$$

to arrive at the first equality...

**Question:** How should I solve this exercise?

Comment: Here are some comments: We have $$ P(|Z|\geq z) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_{z}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx. $$ The constant factor is doubled. As for IbP, you may let $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x) = -e^{-x^2/2}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you for your reply! Could you elaborate a bit more why the constant is doubled?

Comment: The reason is in fact simple. We have $P(|Z| \geq z) = 2P(Z \geq z)$ because of the symmetry of $Z$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks!

Comment: @SangchulLee I tried some more using your useful comments, but I don't get how to derive the $\mathcal{O}$ part. Do you happen to know how to get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

\begin{align*}
P(|Z|\geq z)
&= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_{z}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \left( \left[ -e^{-x^2/2} \cdot \frac{1}{x} \right]_{z}^{\infty} - \int_{z}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x^2} \, dx \right) \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \left( \frac{e^{-z^2/2}}{z} - \int_{z}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x^2} \, dx \right).
\end{align*}

As a by-product, if $z > 0$ then we have

$$ \int_{z}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx \leq \frac{e^{-z^2/2}}{z}. $$

Then, again assuming $z > 0$, we find that

$$ \int_{z}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x^2} \, dx
\leq \frac{1}{z^2} \int_{z}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx
\leq \frac{e^{-z^2/2}}{z^3}. $$

This is enough to conclude the desired asymptotic formula.